# Adding RSS feed view

Tags: views, feeds

I was trying to add a RSS feed view in Drupal 8. I selected *feed row style* for *Fields*, and clicked on *Save and edit*, but I got this message.

> Row style plugin requires specifying which views fields to use for RSS item.

> [image: screenshot]

What does this message mean?

Comment: It probably means you don't need an unformatted list of **teasers**, but of **fields**. So under PAGE DISPLAY SETTINGS change teasers to fields. Or choose a different "Feed row style".

Comment: Thank you @leymannx. I changed 'Unformatted list' to 'Grid' and 'Teasers' to 'Fields'.  I have updated the srceenshot. Still getting the same mesage.

Comment: The error is confusing and probably caused by the code not verifying some conditions. Apart from changing the setting used to create a view, there is another method to get the view exactly the way you want it, and with a feed.

Comment: Why would you choose grid for an RSS feed? It has to be a simple list.

Comment: @leymannx I am trying to recreate a website. In that site grid is chosen for RSS. That's why I selected grid. I have added the original site's settings screenshots.

Comment: Please don't change the meaning of the question once it gets answers.

Answer (score 3):

The error just means that the feed row style require fields, but the view being created doesn't have fields.
The error is confusing, since I can create a view like that and add a feed.

There are two ways for not getting that error: The first one is selecting *Table* as *Display format*, and *Content* as *Feed row style*, in the page to create a new view.

> [image: screenshot]

In this way, I got the view without errors.

> [image: screenshot]

The second way is creating a view without telling the Views module to include a feed. It will be created after.

On the page shown to create a view, I don't select *Include an RSS feed*, and I click on *Save and edit*.

> [image: screenshot]

On the next page, I click on *+Add* and choose *Feed* on the drop-down list that appears. (I cannot show it on the screenshot, but I can choose between *Attachment*, *Block*, *Embed*, *Entity reference*, *Feed*, and *Page*.)

> [image: screenshot]

On the next page, on the bottom, you will get the following error.

> Display "Feed" uses a path but the path is undefined.

> [image: screenshot]

Click on *No path is set*, and enter the path you want for the feed.

> [image: screenshot]

This is close to what the Views module gives you, with an exception: The feed is not attached to any page, since it says *Attached to: **None***.

Click on *None* and select to which pages the feed must be attached.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So is it not possible to select 'Fields' in Format -> Show ?

Comment: If the view is not using fields, the feed cannot use them too.